# Is it possible to send file from one web page to another in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp-client

i have two domains like domain1 and domain2.

I'm uploading file to domain1's server with `server.SaveAs` method which uploads file to domain1

i want to upload same file to domain2 as well as domain1. can you people suggest me how can i do that.

how can i pass docx file into querystring ?

please do not ask me to use ftp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725416/uploading-files-across-domains-in-asp-net

Comment: You can simply upload the file in another domain if you have the permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved when we created an asp.net web api and deployed it to 2nd domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload file to other domain from the server side using the [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) When the file is uploaded to the domain of current page and is saved. You can upload it to other domain using the URL.

```
string fileName = "PhysicalPath";
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(uriString,fileName);
```

Comment: Adil it works fine on Desktop application. but i want to use it on web page. I have same page and one fileupload control, for domain1 `fileupload.SaveAs()` works but it did not work for domain2(followed the method you mentioned)